# DBContext CompiledQuery

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

`CompiledQuery` has been used in LINQ. It accepts two arguments, first is the `DataContext` and the **return type**. Basically, my problem is that `DataContext` has been deprecated in later versions, and I am now using `DbContext`. So my question is, is there a way to use `CompiledQuery` functionality with `DBContext` as parameter? Or what is the method that has the same functionality as `CompiledQuery`? I'm trying to retrieve more than 20k records, and the LINQ query that I have is simple, but it takes time to fetch those records.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from EF5 the queries are automatically compiled; so, in fact, you can use a standard query and get the same effect.

Comment: Yes, but I have pagination on my page, and every time i hit 'next page', it will perform the query, which would take time to compile.

Comment: Well, if you're going to load 20.000 records every time you need to load a single page, well, I don't think the problem is in the compilation. Are you showing 20.000 records per page? Because if not, as I suppose, you need to use .Skip() and .Take() on the query to avoid excessive loading of records you're not going to show.

Comment: @user6081188 That isn't correct. Starting from EF5, there is a compilation cache.

Comment: However it is worth noting that with `CompiledQuery` you can do a optimize the timing of the compilation to the startup of your application. But it is probably not worth the abstraction leak that it entails.